# how to display all the data from database in django html table

Tags: django

I want to display the data from database using html table in django.

im using mysql and already connected to django.

here is my view :

```
def table_list(request):
    tablelst = CompanyRate.objects.all()
    context = {'tablelst': tablelst}
    return render(request, 'articleapp/table_list.html', context)
```

Model:

```
class CompanyRate(models.Model):
    date = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    notice_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    event = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    basic_amount = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    num_of_company = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    avg_of_1365 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    hd_rate = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    hd_num = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    hj_rate = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    hj_num = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    hm_rate = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    hm_num = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'company_rate'
```

articleapp/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('table_list/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='articleapp/table_list.html'), 
name='table_list'),
```

]

main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('articles/', include('articleapp.urls')),
```

]

table_list.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}

<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
<tbody>

    {% for article in tablelst%}
        <tr>
         
            <td>{{ article.date }}</td>
            <td>{{ article.notice_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ article.event }}</td>
            <td>{{ article.basic_amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ article.num_of_company }}</td>
            <td>{{ article.avg_of_1365 }}</td>
            <td>{{ article.hd_rate }}</td>
            <td>{{ article.hd_num }}</td>
            <td>{{ article.hj_rate }}</td>
            <td>{{ article.hj_num }}</td>
            <td>{{ article.hm_rate }}</td>
            <td>{{ article.hm_num }}</td>
            <td>{{ article.url }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <tbody>
</table>
```

{% endblock %}

I did something like this but, td is not working. nothing happens. Please help

Comment: Replace `query_results` with `tablelst`

Comment: i replaced it but still doesnt work

Comment: try to put {{tablelst}} in view, if it not working, you have to check from views.py or urls.py andr you can print(tablelst) in views.py and check console in terminal to verify it is working

Answer (score 1):

in your views.py u are passing context so for rendering it in html you hav to pass

```
def table_list(request):
    company_list = CompanyRate.objects.all()
    context = {'company_list': company_list }
    return render(request, 'articleapp/table_list.html', context)
```

so in you html pass that context

```
{% for companyrate in company_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ companyrate.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ companyrate.date }}</td>
            <td>{{ companyrate.notice_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ companyrate.event }}</td>
            <td>{{ companyrate.basic_amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ companyrate.num_of_company }}</td>
            <td>{{ companyrate.avg_of_1365 }}</td>
            <td>{{ companyrate.hd_rate }}</td>
            <td>{{ companyrate.hd_num }}</td>
            <td>{{ companyrate.hj_rate }}</td>
            <td>{{ companyrate.hj_num }}</td>
            <td>{{ companyrate.hm_rate }}</td>
            <td>{{ companyrate.hm_num }}</td>
            <td>{{ companyrate.url }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

you have to call the model with his name and in your models it showing you model name is companyrate

Comment: i replaced query_result -> tablelst but still doesn't work

Comment: did you import you modes in your views.py

Comment: and why are u suing article.id model name is company rate i am edit my answer

Comment: oh it supposed to be erased. yes i imported my model in views.py

Comment: is you models is visible in admin panel